# Logging in Scrapy

Tags: python, logging, documentation, scrapy

I am having trouble with logging in scrapy, and most of what I can find is out of date.

I have set `LOG_FILE="log.txt"` in the `settings.py` file and from the documentation, this should work:

> Scrapy provides a logger within each Spider instance, that can be accessed and used like this:

```
import scrapy

class MySpider(scrapy.Spider):

    name = 'myspider'
    start_urls = ['http://scrapinghub.com']

    def parse(self, response):
        self.logger.info('Parse function called on %s', response.url)
```

But when I do:

```
class MySpider(CrawlSpider):
    #other code
    def parse_page(self,response):
        self.logger.info("foobar")
```

I get nothing. If I set

```
logger = logging.basicConfig(filename="log.txt",level=logging.INFO)
```

At the top of my file, after my imports, it creates a log file, and the default output gets logged just fine, but

```
class MySpider(CrawlSpider):
    #other code
    def parse_page(self,response):
        logger.info("foobar")
```

Fails to make an appearance. I have also tried putting it in the class `__init__`, as such:

```
def __init__(self, *a, **kw):
    super(FanfictionSpider, self).__init__(*a, **kw)
    logging.basicConfig(filename="log.txt",level=logging.INFO)
```

I once again get no output to the file, just to the console, and `foobar` does not show up. Can someone please direct me on how to correctly log in Scrapy?

Comment: Have you checked [official documentation on logging?](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/logging.html#logging-settings) You should set log filename and other details in `settings.py` file.

Comment: @Granitosaurus Yes, I said so at the beginning of the question, and referenced the docs throughout

Answer (score 22, accepted):

For logging I just put this on the spider class:

```
import logging
from scrapy.utils.log import configure_logging 


class SomeSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    configure_logging(install_root_handler=False)
    logging.basicConfig(
        filename='log.txt',
        format='%(levelname)s: %(message)s',
        level=logging.INFO
    )
```

This will put all scrapy output into the project root directory as a `log.txt` file

If you want to log something manually you shouldn't use the scrapy logger, it's deprecated. Just use the python one

```
import logging
logging.error("Some error")
```

Answer (score 2):

It seems that you're not calling your `parse_page` method at any time.
Try to commenting your `parse` method and you're going to receive a `NotImplementedError` because you're starting it and you're saying it 'do nothing'.

Maybe if you implement your `parse_page` method it'll work

```
def parse(self, response):
    self.logger.info('Russia terrorist state %s', response.url)
    self.parse_page(response)
```

Answer (score 2):

I was unable to make @Rafael Almeda's solution work until I added the following to the import section of my spider.py code:

```
from scrapy.utils.log import configure_logging
```