# Scrapy logging example using explicit calls to Python logging

Tags: python, scrapy

I have been trying to find a good example that explains how to properly set up Scrapy logging using Python as suggested in [Scrapy official documentation](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/logging.html).

I have seen some solutions like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38413829/logging-in-scrapy) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11942403/how-to-use-scrapy-log-module-with-custom-log-handler?noredirect=1&lq=1)

But all these approaches looks deprecated .....

Does anyone know a good example on how to implement logging using "*explicit calls to the Python standard logging*" ?

Scrapy's documentation is lacking a good example, especially something like specifying multiple log files, say one for 'errors' and one for 'warnings'.