# Logging to a file using Scrapy and Crochet libraries

Tags: python, logging, scrapy, twisted

I'm running [Scrapy](https://scrapy.org/) from scripts, using [Crochet](https://pypi.org/project/crochet/) library in order to block codes. Now I'm trying to dump logs into a file, but it starts to redirect logs to `STDOUT` for some reason. I doubt the `Crochet` library in my mind, but I don't have any clues so far.

1. How can I debug this kind of problems? Please share your debugging know-hows with me.
2. How can I fix it so that I dump logs into a file?

```
import logging

import crochet
import scrapy
from scrapy import crawler
from scrapy.utils import log

crochet.setup()

class BlogSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'blogspider'
    start_urls = ['https://blog.scrapinghub.com']

    def parse(self, response):
        for idx, title in enumerate(response.css('.post-header>h2')):
            if idx == 10:
                return
            logging.info({'title': title.css('a ::text').get()})

@crochet.wait_for(timeout=None)
def crawl():
    runner = crawler.CrawlerRunner()
    deferred = runner.crawl(BlogSpider)
    return deferred

log.configure_logging(settings={'LOG_FILE': 'my.log'})
logging.info("Starting...")
crawl()
```

Comment: Does [it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38413829/logging-in-scrapy) help you?

Comment: @Piron Thank you but it doesn't help. Calling `scrapy.utils.log.configure_logging(install_root_handler=False)` in `Spider` class definition doesn't solve this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only thing that was needed was passing the `log settings` also to `CrawlerRunner`.

```
import logging

import crochet
import scrapy
from scrapy import crawler
from scrapy.utils import log

crochet.setup()

class BlogSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'blogspider'
    start_urls = ['https://blog.scrapinghub.com']

    def parse(self, response):
        for idx, title in enumerate(response.css('.post-header>h2')):
            if idx == 10:
                return
            logging.info({'title': title.css('a ::text').get()})

@crochet.wait_for(timeout=None)
def crawl():
    runner = crawler.CrawlerRunner(settings=log_settings)
    deferred = runner.crawl(BlogSpider)
    return deferred

log_settings = {'LOG_FILE': 'my.log'}
log.configure_logging(settings=log_settings)
logging.info("Starting...")
crawl()
```

Answer (score 0):

I see you are settings log settings for scrapy while you log using `logging.info` that would send the log message to python's root logger rather than scrapy's root logger**. Try using `self.logger.info("whatever")` inside a spyder instance as [scrapy initializes a logger instance in each object](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/logging.html#logging-from-spiders).  or set logging handler for the root logger using

```
# optional log formatting
format=logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')
file_handler = logging.FileHandler('my.log'), mode='w')
file_handler.setFormatter(format)
file_handler.name = 'file_level_handler' # optional
root_logger = logging.getLogger()
root_logger.addHandler(file_handler)
```

**I read scrapy sets (python's) root logger, so may be I am wrong but apparantly your settings are not being emitted to python's root logger.